# How can I setting robots (Index Follow) inside cms > pages?

Tags: magento, indexing, content-management-system

how can I setting robots (Index Follow) inside Magento backend > cms > pages ?
Do I need to use xml layout in Custom design > Custom Layout Update XML ? Or there is a tab where i can put robot settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on a page-by-page basis by using the Custom Layout Update XML. In admin CMS > Manage Pages select your page, navigate to the design tab and in the Custom Layout Update field, insert the following:

```
 <reference name="head">
    <action method="setRobots"><value>INDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
 </reference>
```

You can vary to suit ...  NOINDEX, FOLLOW  or INDEX, NOFOLLOW` etc. There is no default robots tab.